# Dynamic where condition in CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a query in Spring boot:
I am using CrudRepository where i need to declare method names for all possible combination of where conditions being used in project. Can we declare a method in CrudRepository which can accept dynamic where condition?

Suppose i have a table named "Student" which is having 20 columns. I don't want to define all possible combination of methods names in CrudRepository for those 20 fields. I need a generic method which can accept a json object as parameter and return records based on the where condition passed as json object. Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: You can define StudentCustomeRepository interface and extends CrudRepository and StudentCustomeRepository in your StudentRepository interface. Second step you will use CriteriaBuilder in your StudentCustomeRepositoryImpl

Comment: or use querydsl [core.extensions.queryds](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are called [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html).
These allow for more precise queries.

It is nicely expained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries) (take a look at 5. Using JPA Specifications).